# "Application Instantiation Error" with #__session table

Tags: joomla-3.x, session

Error displaying the error page:

> **Application Instantiation Error**:
>   No database selected SQL=SELECT `session_id` FROM `n0n8z_session` WHERE `session_id` = 'iqi1ntjfnva5c487rajj790a74' LIMIT 0, 1

This error occurs when I try to load a Joomla site into my localhost.

My configuration is correct. What can be problem?

Comment: From your Q **'Session doesn't exist joomla'** posted on SO, I can see in your comment _"in phpmyadmin, only some tables displayed. But in mysql/data folder all tables exist"_   that obviously process _"I have copied my project and its database to wamp server."_ somehow went wrong. How did you restore live site on Wamp, did you use Akeeba Backup or something else?

Comment: @MirkoMikan, what is Akeeba Backup? I just transfered my site from one pc to another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your Q '[Session doesn't exist joomla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35669237/session-doesnt-exist-joomla)' posted on SO, I can see in your comment "i*n phpmyadmin, only some tables displayed. But in mysql/data folder all tables exist*" that obviously process "*I have copied my project and its database to wamp server.*" somehow went wrong.

For transfering Joomla site correctly I would recommend using leading Joomla extension [Akeeba Backup](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/akeeba-backup). Install free Core version on source site, and follow [documentation](https://www.akeebabackup.com/documentation/akeeba-backup-documentation/a-typical-backup-restoration-workflow.html) to create installable archive, which will have all it's files and database(s). That archive you will then unpack in the root folder of destination site, go to it's URL in browser, complete Mini-Installation process which will correctly upload database(s) to new location and create correct configuration file for the new site, thus creating exact copy of source site.

I have been using this extension since 2007 and Joomla 1.0, when it was still
called JoomlaPack. Also, searching JSE for 'akeeba' will yield bunch of questions, answers and comments regrading this must-have J! Ext.

Comment: very thanks! I will try it and write the result tomorrow. I hope your advice will help me.

Comment: You're welcome. I didn't want to confuse you more with some tips&tricks, but I personally prefer NOT to follow instructions to the letter, and NOT to create .JPA file, for whose extracting on the destination site one needs kickstart.php file. For 99% of hosting environments which I have used (and I have worked on 20+ of them), it is safe enough to choose .ZIP file in backup job configuration, and to simply unpack that backup archive on destination site, using either Winzip for localhost, or built-in Extract Archive in every cPanel's File Manager for remote hosts. Anyway...

Comment: thanks. Akeeba backup component has perfectly worked for me! That is cool!

Comment: I didnt understand your last comment. Why dont u prefer using akeeba?

Comment: @ITEngineer - Cause when you have experience backing up and restoring sites, it's quicker to do it manually in most cases.

Comment: @Lodder, that is clear. I have an experience, but sometimes you face such errors like in my post.

Comment: @ITEngineer - Glad it worked for you. If you are satisfied with the answer please mark it accepted.